# $('.testingConfirmation').show(); is not working in my fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, kendo-ui

- when I enter the path in the text box and hit save button.
- I need to show confirmation window.
- I debugged the code after the below line. I don't see confirmation box 
  `$('.testingConfirmation').show();`
- Can you guys tell me how to fix it?
- providing relevant jQuery,HTML and CSS code below.
- you can see the bug in the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/XY7HT/63/

```
$('.testingConfirmation').show();

$('.testingConfirmation').hide();


.testingConfirmation {
  position: relative;
}
.testingConfirmation .kPopupConfirmationBox {
  display: block;
  z-index: 3;
  left: calc(50% - 175px);
  width: 350px;
  position: absolute;
}


.testingConfirmation {
  display: none;
}

<div class="testingConfirmation">
  <div class="kendopobUpBox kendoWindow kPopupConfirmationBox">
    <div class="row kendoPopUpGridCollection kendoPopUpContent lineHeightInputs">
      <div class="kendoContent">delete player</div>
    </div><div class="clearFloat"></div>

    <div class="row kendoPopUpFooter textAligncenterImp">
      <button class="commonBtn" type="button" id ="deleteDocumentYes" ">Yes</button>
      <button class="clearBtn" type="button" id ="deleteDocumentNo" >No</button>
    </div><div class="clearFloat"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First you have to fix the Type-Errors in your fiddle. `TypeError: $(...).kendoGrid is not a function` and `TypeError: $(...).show(...).kendoWindow is not a function`

Comment: @JoshuaK thanks for your reply...but I dont see any error in browser in console

Comment: I see two typos in your markup which likely aren't helping anything, although may not be related to your issue. The class `kendopobUpBox` seems to be a typo, and you have an extra `"` in the markup for your Yes button.